# Python map method

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list `my_list = [{"index": 1}, {"index": 2}]`

and I want to build a new one so that the result will look like :

```
[
{"values":{"index": 1}, "key": "Dummy"},
{"values":{"index": 2}, "key": "Dummy"}
]
```

this loop way is working :

```
res = []
for a in my_list:
    obj = {}
    obj["values"] = a
    obj["key"] = "Dummy"
    res.append(obj)
```

but I wanted to know if there is a way to re write it using pyhton map method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
print(list(map(lambda x: {"values": x, "key": "Dummy"}, my_list)))
```